# redirect a div of a page but I need it redirect animate and scroll in js

Tags: css, html

I have page xyz.com that has a div id="abc". So I want to redirect to div abc from another page `www.xyz.com/#abc`.

can you tell me how to get xyz.com/#abc top position in number? I tried in body

```
var hash_value = window.location.hash.replace('#', '');// get abc

var top = $(hash_value).offset().top;
```

is not working . I want to redirect xyz.com/#abc  will animate and scroll to #abc .

I have many div like #abc so I need something dynamic js code like

```
var top = $(this.hash).offset().top;
$('html, body').animate({scrollTop: top}, 500, function() {});
```

its working when I put

```
var top=1300;
```

1300 is the top position of #abc ;I want top position get dynamically for #add #bar

dynamically getting #abc is not possible then is it possible to pass value with

```
<a href="www.xyz.com/#abc">click here</a>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You will need javascript. You can do something as scroll. When you load the page, then after that scroll the page 28px down as

```
$('#abc').scrollTo(28); // scroll 28px down
```

You will use this function inside `$('body').load(function ()`

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'scrollTo'

Comment: question edited . sorry couldn't ask the problem properly at first . actually idea didn't developed properly until you guy's gave solution.

Answer (score 0):

Put

```css
#abc {padding-top:28px; margin-top:-28px;}
```

in your css.

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/AGzX7/5/

You can test by showing http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/AGzX7/5/show (normal view) or http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/AGzX7/5/show#abc (with abc on top, starting below the menu bar).

(Make sure your window is narrow enough to enable #abc to scroll to the top, otherwise you won't see it!)

Comment: This working successfully , But I prefer scrolltop , because it make a animation .

Comment: question edited . sorry couldn't ask the problem properly at first . actually idea didn't developed properly until you guy's gave solution.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Afzaal

```
$('body').load(function(){
    $('#abc').scrollTo(0, 28) // using plain javascript
})
```

or

```
$('body').load(function(){
    $('#abc').scrollTop(28) // using jQuery
})
```

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'scrollTo'

Comment: can you tell me how get http://localhost/#abc , I can get #abc top position in number? var top = $(this.hash).offset().top; is not working . I want to redirect http://localhost/#abc  will animate and scroll to #abc

Comment: question edited . sorry couldn't ask the problem properly at first . actually idea didn't developed properly until you guy's gave solution.

Comment: @Paul, the "plain javascript" example is not really plain javascript.

Comment: @MrLister answering on StackOverflow from work is really not OK :)).